# Shifting layout up when keyboard pops up

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So I have a `EditText` on the bottom of the screen for user input and when I click on it, the keyboard pops up and it shifts it up but the issue is how it is being shifted. Rather than moving the `EditText` with the keyboard, the keyboard will show and half a second later, the `EditText` gets snapped into place. And when I close the keyboard, the `EditText` remains the extended size for half a second before going back to the original size.

The question is, is it possible for a smooth transition?

Not sure if this will affect the outcome but it is within a `Fragment`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:backgroundTint="#c1c1c1">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ListViewChat"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout4" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
            android:hint="Enter a message..."
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonSend"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonSend"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonSend"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:maxLength="120"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@null" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:src="@drawable/linebreak2px"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try setting `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in your parent container. This should effectively smoothen the sudden changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

inside your AndroidManifest.xml, inside your activity, let me know if it works

Comment: It is still the same as before unfortunately, the `EditText` is getting locked into place after the soft keyboard has fully appeared and get locked back into the original place after the keyboard if fully off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below in your AndroidManifest.xml where your acivity is declared in which you have the fragment that your are working

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

and let me know if it works